# Twitter API - pull hashtags from a single user

Tags: api, twitter, hashtag

I am trying to pull all tweets that include #multitouch from a single twitter. (not just pull everyone that ever tweets using #multitouch, just from one person)

my code right now [which just pulls by hashtag]:
 $(document).ready(function () {

```
$.getJSON('http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=%23multitouch:&screen_name=25KDIGITAL:&callback=?', function (json) { 
             for(i = 0; i < 3; i++)
             {
                $("#TweetBar").append("<li>" + json.results[i].text + "</li>", "<p>" + json.results[i].from_user + "</p>");
             }


             //$("#TweetBar").show(2500, 'linear');
         });

     });
```

is this at all possible? thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, just make sure you're using the right URL to pull the data

http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=%23multitouch%20from:25KDIGITAL
(query: "#multitouch from:25KDIGITAL")